# Area doesn't use the right view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've added an admin area to my mvc 4 website to easily maintain my website. When i visit mywebsite.com/admin/home the right controller gets called but it goes to my wrong home view.

So i've one area called admin and my main website controllers and views aren't in an area (i don't know if that can cause problems)

My routes:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Admin_default",
    url: "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new string[] { "Topsite.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
 );

     routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        namespaces: new string[] { "Topsite.Controllers" }
    );
```

Note: I've a custom view engine.

ViewEngine:

```
              AreaViewLocationFormats = new[] {

        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/%1/{1}/{0}.cshtml",

        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/%1/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",

        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/%1/Shared/{0}.cshtml",

        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/%1/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"

    };


    AreaMasterLocationFormats = new[] {

        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/%1/{1}/{0}.cshtml",

        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/%1/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",

        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/%1/Shared/{0}.cshtml",

        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/%1/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"

    };


    AreaPartialViewLocationFormats = new[] {

        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/%1/{1}/{0}.cshtml",

        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/%1/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",

        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/%1/Shared/{0}.cshtml",

        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/%1/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"

    };



    ViewLocationFormats = new[] {

        "~/Themes/" + Theme  + "/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",

        "~/Themes/" + Theme  + "/Views/%1/Shared/{0}.cshtml",

    };



    MasterLocationFormats = new[] {

     "~/Themes/" + Theme  + "/Views/%1/{1}/{0}.cshtml",

    "~/Themes/" + Theme  + "/Views/%1/Shared/{0}.cshtml",


    };


    PartialViewLocationFormats = new[] {

         "~/Themes/" + Theme  + "/Views/%1/{1}/{0}.cshtml",

        "~/Themes/" + Theme  + "/Views/%1/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",

          "~/Themes/" + Theme  + "/Views/%1/Shared/{0}.cshtml",

         "~/Themes/" + Theme  + "/Views/%1/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"

    };
```

If someone could help me that would be great!

Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add a file named:

```
_ViewStart.cshtml
```

Under each area views folder, And edit the file to point to the root layout like this:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Areas/Admin/Shared/Views/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem, i've added the file but it goes to the wrong viewstart file.

Comment: Have you registered your custom view engine in Global.asax?

Comment: Yes i have registered it there